# Is android:layout_weight only for LinearLayout or you can use it in RelativeLayout too?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

If android:`layout_weight` is only for `LinearLayout` Why?

Answer (score 1):

Read **[Layout Weight](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight)**

This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.

A relative layout displays its views relative to one another, so order is not that important.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, so what if I want to insert an EditText (and it increases right according to the size of the screen for example when we write an email, it increases (the box) so you mean whenever there is EditText should be placed in the LinearLayout? so we can apply layout_weight? and we cannot use EditText in RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_weight is property of **LinearLayout** and it inherits this property to its child so in your case, if your child is RelativeLayout then We can use android:layout_weight with RelativeLayout.

see below example

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**THAT'S IT**

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, so what if I want to insert at EditText (and it increases right according to the size of the screen for example when we write an email, it increases (the box) so you mean whenever there is EditText should be placed in the LinearLayout? so we can apply layout_weight? and we cannot use EditText in RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout is not having weight property but ConstraintLayout have weight properties like LinearLayout.

`layout_constraintHorizontal_weight` 
`layout_constraintVertical_weight`

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, so what if I want to insert at EditText (and it increases right according to the size of the screen for example when we write an email, it increases (the box) so you mean whenever there is EditText should be placed in the LinearLayout? so we can apply layout_weight? and we cannot use EditText in RelativeLayout?